# Mount and Blade Warband completely crashes Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, games, radeon

M&B Warband occasionally crashes my entire computer and forces me to do a force restart this happens more often if I mod the game but even when I play vanilla it still happens.

**Computer Stats**

**OS:** Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (64-bit)

**Memory:** 5 Gib

**Processor:** AMD A4-4300M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics × 2

**Built in Graphics:** Gallium 0.4 on AMD ARUBA

**Crash Text**

Because it completely stops my computer for working I had to take a picture of my screen with my phone so it might not be great quality. I also have to use an imgur link because my rep isn't high enough to have pictures here. (Link https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnBUq.jpg).

Also I am new to Ubuntu so it may just be a stupid mistake I'm making.